# How to avoid downcasting while having interface and base classes?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm sure i'm missing something elemental here, but i cannot get my head around it.

Let's say we have several possible implementations of a `Manager`class which handles objects of type `Base`. It should be possible to define which implementation to use at runtime.

Based on the implementation of the `Manager`, they will have to set and get specific properties from `Base`, therefore the derivations `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` which they use internally. Is there a way to circumvent the need for downcasting the parameter in the `Handle` methods in order to get to the implementation-specific properties?

```
class Base { /* Abstract class with common properties */ };
class DerivedA : public Base { /* DerivedA-specific properties */ };
class DerivedB : public Base { /* DerivedB-specific properties */ };

class IManager { /* These functions must be implemented by every Manager implementation */
public:
    virtual Base* Create() = 0;
    virtual void Handle(Base*) = 0;
};

class AManager : public IManager
{
public:
    Base* Create() override { return new DerivedA(); }
    void Handle(Base* pFoo) override 
    { 
        // Now if we want to access pFoo's specific properties, we will need to dynamic_cast it
    }
};

class BManager : public IManager
{
public:
    Base* Create() override { return new DerivedB(); }
    void Handle(Base* pBar) override { /* same here */ }
};

void Run(bool useAManager)
{
    IManager* pManager = nullptr;

    if (useAManager)
        pManager = new AManager();
    else
        pManager = new BManager();

    Base* pData = pManager->Create();
    /* use Base specific properties ... */
    pManager->Handle(pData);
}
```

Edit: Thank you all for the valuable input. I will accept @jpo38's post since it provides a possible solution to this problem. After some consideration however, I found that there is an underlying problem with the class design.

Comment: Maybe http://www.tolchz.net/?p=33 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064247/function-overriding-with-different-return-types might help.

Comment: IF AManager only manages DerivedA, consider using templates.

Comment: First you grab a `Data` pointer from `pManager`, deliberately forgetting the type behind it. Then you pass it back to `pManager`, but it's too late, the type is forgotten. Perhaps you can keep the data and the manager (before upcasting!) always tied together. How about storing `pManager` (with the correct type) *in* the data?

Comment: Your `AManager::Create()` is committed to the concrete type `DeriveA`. Then why not `AManager::Handle()`? Store the `DeriveA` as member in `AManager` and use it directly in `Handler()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). In your example, this would be:

```
class DerivedA;
class DerivedB;
class Visitor
{ 
public:
    virtual void visitA( DerivedA& a ) = 0;
    virtual void visitB( DerivedB& b ) = 0;
};


class Base 
{ 
public:
    virtual void Accept( Visitor& visitor ) = 0;
};

class DerivedA : public Base 
{ 
public:
    virtual void Accept( Visitor& visitor ) { visitor.visitA( *this ); }
};

class DerivedB : public Base 
{ 
public:
    virtual void Accept( Visitor& visitor ) { visitor.visitB( *this ); }
};
```

Then, from AManager or BManager:

```
void Handle(Base* pFoo) 
{ 
    class MyVisitor : public Visitor
    {
    public:
        virtual void visitA( DerivedA& a )
        {
             // do somethiong specific to a, you have access to DerivedA
        }
        virtual void visitB( DerivedB& b )
        {
             // do somethiong specific to b, you have access to DerivedB
        }
    };
    MyVisitor v;
    pFoo->Accept( v );
}
```

The disadvantage of visitor pattern is that you'll have to define a new visitor class every time you'll want to do something specific.

You can also consider doing this (but I definitely recommend visitors, very helful if you add DerivedC later or want to share some specific operation through shared visitor classes).

```
class Base 
{ 
public:
    virtual DerivedA* GetAsA() = 0;
    virtual DerivedB* GetAsB() = 0;
};

class DerivedA : public Base 
{ 
public:
    virtual DerivedA* GetAsA() { return this; }
    virtual DerivedB* GetAsB() { return NULL; }
};

class DerivedB : public Base 
{ 
public:
    virtual DerivedA* GetAsA() { return NULL; }
    virtual DerivedB* GetAsB() { return this; }
};
```

Then, from AManager or BManager:

```
void Handle(Base* pFoo) 
{ 
    if ( pFoo->GetAsA() )
    {
        // use GetAsA to access DerivedA object avoiding downcasting
    }
    if ( pFoo->GetAsB() )
    {
        // use GetAsB to access DerivedB object avoiding downcasting
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the drawbacks of using Visitor instead of, or in addition to, the code. One either already knows how to write a Visitor, or will need a lot more explanation than you have provided (i.e. none). You have stated "The disadvantage of visitor pattern is that you'll have to define a new visitor class", but there's a more serious one, the circular dependency it introduces.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If you absolutely need to treat specific subtypes in a different way, `dynamic_cast` is the cleanest solution.

Strictly speaking, the real problem here starts at the word "properties". An object-oriented base class does not have properties but *operations*, and when you accept a `Base` parameter, all you are interested in are those abstract operations. In completely clean object-oriented designs, at least.

Your class design is just not cleanly object-oriented, that's all. But that's not a problem in itself. If it works for you and the code is easy to read and maintain, then everything is fine.